# How to remove substring from the end of the string

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I remove a specific substring if this substring is at the end of the string?

In one column, there is `***` at the end - value = 'str***ing***' and I want to strip `***` so the value would be 'str***ing'. I want to delete this substring only from the end of the string.

This is what I have done so far:

I though about `SUBSTR()` but it wants coordinates but the string can be different sizes.

```
UPDATE final_table SET parametre = ???  WHERE parametre like '%***'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use substr(your_column , -num)

```
substr(User.id, -6)

UPDATE final_table SET parametre =  substr(parametre,1, length(parametre)-3) 
WHERE parametre like '%***'
```